# CSS display (cannot top valign)

Tags: css

[image: Display problem]
   You can see from the picture that the input(type=number) and button(rate) cannot top valign
   This is my code.. How can I fix this problem?

```
 <form class="formRate" action="/rate" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="contentid" value="<%= photo.id %>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="source" value="<%= photo.source %>" />
    <input type="number" name="score" min="1" max="5" style="width:30px;"/>
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Rate"/>
    </form>
```

Comment: @MelanciaUK I just used the bootstrap. I did not write the specific css code for this? Is it the reason?

Comment: I wondered why you said the `valign` didn't work, if you actually didn't set it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
input { float: left; }

.formRate { overflow: auto; }
```

That should help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use that in your CSS :

```
input {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing the CSS, but try adding

```
<style>
  form, input { 
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try using the `vertical-align` CSS property, setting it to `top`.

There are nuances with using this property, to be sure, depending on the element types and whatnot; admittedly, though, I haven't memorised where and when you *should* use this, and I'm just happy enough when it works.